# Insert php into JS file

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I venture into wordpress codes. I am not a programmer, but with the help of content on the web I managed to build my website.

I have a problem, which despite the numerous researches, I still haven't been able to solve.

I have the following .min.js code that is responsible for the social sharing buttons.

```
    (function(a){window.ShareLink=function(b,c){var d,e={},f=function(a){var b=a.substr(0,e.classPrefixLength);return b===e.classPrefix?a.substr(e.classPrefixLength):null},g=function(a){d.on("click",function(){h(a)})},h=function(a){var b="";if(e.width&&e.height){var c=screen.width/2-e.width/2,d=screen.height/2-e.height/2;b="toolbar=0,status=0,width="+e.width+",height="+e.height+",top="+d+",left="+c}var f=ShareLink.getNetworkLink(a,e),g=/^https?:\/\//.test(f),h=g?"":"_self";open(f,h,b)},i=function(){a.each(b.classList,function(){var a=f(this);if(a)return g(a),!1})},j=function(){a.extend(e,ShareLink.defaultSettings,c),["title","text"].forEach(function(a){e[a]=e[a].replace("#","")}),e.classPrefixLength=e.classPrefix.length},k=function(){d=a(b)};(function(){j(),k(),i()})()},ShareLink.networkTemplates={twitter:"https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text={text}{url}",pinterest:"https://www.pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url={url}&media={image}",facebook:"https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u={url}",vk:"https://vkontakte.ru/share.php?url={url}&title={title}&description={text}&image={image}",linkedin:"https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url={url}&title={title}&summary={text}&source={url}",odnoklassniki:"https://connect.ok.ru/offer?url={url}&title={title}&imageUrl={image}",tumblr:"https://tumblr.com/share/link?url={url}",delicious:"https://del.icio.us/save?url={url}&title={title}",google:"https://plus.google.com/share?url={url}",digg:"",reddit:"https://reddit.com/submit?url={url}&title={title}",stumbleupon:"https://www.stumbleupon.com/submit?url={url}",pocket:"https://getpocket.com/edit?url={url}",whatsapp:"https://api.whatsapp.com/send?text=️ *{title}*%0A%0A {url}",xing:"https://www.xing.com/app/user?op=share&url={url}",print:"javascript:print()",email:"mailto:?subject={title}&body={text}\n{url}",telegram:"https://telegram.me/share/url?url={url}&text={text}",skype:"https://web.skype.com/share?url={url}"},ShareLink.defaultSettings={title:"",text:"",image:"",url:location.href,classPrefix:"s_",width:640,height:480},ShareLink.getNetworkLink=function(a,b){var c=ShareLink.networkTemplates[a].replace(/{([^}]+)}/g,function(a,c){return b[c]||""});if("email"===a){if(-1<b.title.indexOf("&")||-1<b.text.indexOf("&")){var d={text:b.text.replace(/&/g,"%26"),title:b.title.replace(/&/g,"%26"),url:b.url};c=ShareLink.networkTemplates[a].replace(/{([^}]+)}/g,function(a,b){return d[b]})}return c.indexOf("?subject=&body")&&(c=c.replace("subject=&","")),c}return c},a.fn.shareLink=function(b){return this.each(function(){a(this).data("shareLink",new ShareLink(this,b))})}})(jQuery);
```

The expression {title} retrieves the name of the page, however the title of the post comes with the name of the site, example (headline + name of the site). I need to use the (the_title) function to retrieve just the post name.

I would like to know, if possible step by step, how I put this function inside min.js.

Comment: you can insert php code in script but in inline not in separated file

Comment: Did you add the social sharing buttons using some plugin? If yes, then you should contact the developers of the plugin to ask how to customize it.

Comment: Simply by `<?= "the_title"; ?>`.

Comment: Excuse me for the lack of experience.

In case this (function filter_wp_title ($ title) {) should be placed in the theme's functions.php file?

Another thing, after that as I call it in the min.js file

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by simply applying filter on wp_title to remove site name from page title.

```
function filter_wp_title( $title ) {

    $title = single_post_title( '', false );
    return $title;
}
add_filter( 'wp_title', 'filter_wp_title' );
```